# How to register a new API extension in kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

I'm working [to add port range support to kubernetes](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/23864) so I need to modify the API and schemas to support a new parameter: portrange instead of the traditional port. To do it, I've follow [the official guideline](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/devel/api_changes.md#edit-typesgo) but yet, I'm blocked because when I try to execute:

```
cluster/kubectl.sh create -f restcomm_rc_range.yml
```

returns:

```
error validating "restcomm_rc_range.yml": error validating data: API version "ranges/v2 alpha1" isn't supported, only supports API versions ["extensions/v1beta1" "authentication.k8s.io/v1beta1" "v1" "apps/v1alpha1" "autoscaling/v1" "metrics/v1alpha1" "policy/v1alpha1" "authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1" "batch/v1" "batch/v2alpha1" "componentconfig/v1alpha1"]; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false
```

I've previously executed:

```
./hack/update-all.sh -a && ./hack/build-go.sh
./hack/local-up-cluster.sh
```

And I've [modified all the files](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/compare/master...antonmry:portrange2%232?expand=1), but clearly I'm missing some step here to register the API in the API Server. Any guidance about how to do it? Is this solution suitable for the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to register the API in the APIServer code.  See:

https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/pkg/master/master.go#L245

for an example for v1beta1.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Brendan. It was exactly what I was looking for.